# amazon aws elastic beanstalk. Custom Configuration Files not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a problem with Custom Configuration File in aws elastic beanstalk.

My application is python flask app.

I put 01wsgi.config file into .ebextensions.

and zipped it then upload to elastic beanstalk.

The source deployed well, but the configuration didn't executed.

How can I make it works properly?

directory structure:

```
source_root
  - .ebextensions
     -- 01wsgi.config
  - application
  - application.wsgi
```

01wsgi.config content:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
      WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
      WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
      WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

      <VirtualHost *:80>
      #############
      # TYPES FIX #
      #############
      AddType text/css .css
      AddType text/javascript .js

      ####################
      # GZIP COMPRESSION #
      ####################
      SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
      BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
      BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
      SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
      Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

      Alias /static/(.*)? /opt/python/current/app/application/frontend/static-build/
      <Directory /opt/python/current/app/application/frontend/static-build/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Header append Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, must-revalidate"
      </Directory>

      WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/application.py

      <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      </Directory>

      WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
      python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
      home=/opt/python/current/app
      WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
      WSGIScriptReloading On
      </VirtualHost>
```

I followed document below:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

### SOLVED

Put your wsgi.conf file into .ebextensions directory.

And make a config file that copy wsgi.conf to ondeck.

01wsgi.config content:

```
container_commands:
  replace_wsgi_config:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/wsgi.conf /opt/python/ondeck/wsgi.conf"
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Here is another example showing how to use ebextensions. It´s a PHP example, but if you pay attention it´s just a bunch of shell commands:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38880732/2130610

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add some info about another gotcha: Beanstalk will overwrite your apache hosts file if you make changes that do not execute a full deployment (e.g. change environment variables). In most cases, your web server will stop serving up your app, unless you are not actually customizing `wsgi.conf`.

Now, to be clear, you are correct in that you need to put your WSGI config in the [`.ebextentions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) directory. Then you use a [container command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) to move the configuration file to the location that EB looks at. You can do this safely with this command:

```
# Replace the default wsgi with ours
cp .ebextensions/wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf
```

To prevent your custom `wsgi.conf` from being overwritten during an update that does not execute a deployment, you will need to monkey patch the native EB hook that recreates `wsgi.conf`. I haven't found any docs around this, but [custom hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html#custom-platform-hooks) are documented and the native ones work in the same fashion.

Here is the monkey patch that I have been using:

```
# Elastic Beanstalk always forces generation of apache hosts,
# stop it by returning true in the function that does it
sed '    /return True # DO NOT REGENERATE APACHE HOSTS/d' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py \
  | sed -e 's/def generate_apache_config(params, filename):/def generate_apache_config(params, filename):\n    return True # DO NOT REGENERATE APACHE HOSTS/1' \
  -e 's/if not os.path.exists(WSGI_STAGING_CONFIG):/if not os.path.exists(WSGI_STAGING_CONFIG):\n        return True # DO NOT REGENERATE APACHE HOSTS/1' \
  > /tmp/config.py && mv -f /tmp/config.py /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py
```

SSH into an EB instance and take a look at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py` and you'll see what EB does during deployments or updates to the environment.

Happy AWSing!

Comment: Where do you place the "Monkey Patch"? in your `wsgi.conf`? Is your custom wsgi.conf file placed in the same directory as `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @WayBehind The patch is to delete lines in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py` that re-deploy the default wsgi.conf. There is probably a better way to do this, it's been a long time and I'm not currently using Django on EB.